# Restrict android recording to device inbuilt MIC

Tags: android, audio-recording

I have a application that requires me to record audio from the **device inbuilt mic** and play it with the head phone. The app that i have developed for this application works fine with a head phone without Mic but when a headphone with Mic is plugged it starts recording from the headphones Mic(I dont want this to happen).

I have used `AudioRecord` in my code and below is its constructor

```
mRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            mSampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            mBufferSize);
```

How can I do it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything you can do, since OEMs can customize the routing order as they see fit. On all the devices I've worked on, the headset has had higher priority than the built-in microphone(s) and would be chosen first if available. You could try using the `CAMCORDER` audio source, but this might end up using a microphone located on the back or side of the device (the one that would be used when recording video) rather then the one at the front/bottom.

Comment: I tried using CAMCORDER as an audio source but it results the same.

Comment: Did you find the solution ?